# calculus the following functions could you find the minimum of?

Tags: calculus

In finding the point on the line y=x closest to the point (0,1) which of the following functions could you find the minimum of?

a. $2x^2+2x+2$

b. $x^2-2x+2$

c. $2x^2-2x+1$

d. $2x^2-x+2$

e. $x^2-1$

Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $d$ is the distance, $$d^2=(0-x)^2+(1-y)^2=(0-y)^2+(1-y)^2=2y^2-2y+1=2x^2-2x+1$$

As $d>0,$  $d^2$ will be minimum  $\iff d$ is minimum